# Java Persistence Api долго устанавливает соединение к базе. БД находится на удаленном сервере

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jpa, jsf, persistence

Всем привет, jpa долго устанавливает соединение к базе. 
БД находится на удаленном сервере.
функция вызывающая entityManager

```
 public List<Posts> connect() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        EntityManager em=EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        Query q=em.createQuery("Select p from Posts p");
        result=q.getResultList();
        return result;
    }
```

persistence.xml

org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/temp"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="user03022016"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: "долго" это сколько секунд?

Comment: @Nofate, около 4 -5 секунд

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Сonnection Pull dataSource. Это позволит избежать созданий соединений в процесе работы с приложением и ограничит количество одновременно открытых соединений к базе.

Тут есть примеры как сконфигурить это в Spring
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117191/spring-jdbc-connection-pool-best-practices

В вашем случае можно использовать реализацию пула C3P0 (вконце ноль а не "О")

Comment: спасибо попробую